# Can I use IIS as a server for AFrame?

Tags: iis, aframe

Hi my company is setting up a server for AFrame development and can't use Apache.  Can we use IIS for a server as a host for this dev environment.

Comment: _"can't use Apache"_ - what's the story there?

Comment: [aframe looks like a client-side (i.e. JS) platform](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/introduction/), in which case the choice of webserver is largely irrelevant.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I learned about A-Frame, an open source web framework for building virtual reality (VR) experiences. A-Frame is designed to be compatible with a wide variety of web servers, including Apache, Nginx, and Microsoft IIS. I don't know why you say you can't use Apache, I'm guessing maybe it's because Apache isn't compatible with the OS you're using, or there are specific requirements or constraints in your project.

IIS is a web server developed by Microsoft for Windows-based systems. You can use IIS as a server for AFrame development, especially if your organization already has experience and infrastructure based on Windows systems.